# Can anyone help me understand Polymer core-media-queries?

Tags: polymer

I'm having a bit of confusion when trying to use Polymer's `core-media-query` element to adjust my layout accordingly. I understand how to set the breakpoint for when the query is going to be true, but I'm unsure of how to adjust individual attributes for the element I'm trying to change at the breakpoint.

Here's what I have so far:

```
<core-media-query query="max-width: 884px" queryMatches="{{smallScreen}}">
</core-media-query>
```

and my element:

```
<div class="footer-container" vertical?="{{smallScreen}}"
horizontal?="{{!smallScreen}}" center-justified layout center>
```

Which I found here on Github. It works great for moving the layout to vertical when `smallScreen == true` but I also need to change like, `center-justified` to `end-justified` and some other of the attributes. How do I go about doing this?

I've tried doing this:

```
<div class="left-container" center?="{{smallScreen}}" start?="{{!smallScreen}"
vertical center-justified layout>
```

But it doesn't appear to be doing anything. It gets that it's `!smallScreen` but doesn't seem to see when the query is true. hmm

edit: it appears to work with `center-justified` and `end-justified` just not work cross-axis stuff

Answer (score 0):

you could use conditional templates.

```
<template if="{{smallScreen}}">
  // things to show when smallScreen is true
</template>
<template if={{!smallScreen}}">
  // things to show if smallScreen is false
</template>
```